# I got error when I run bundle install

Tags: ruby

I typed rails s to run my server then I got this:

```
    Warning: Running `gem pristine --all` to regenerate your installed           gemspecs (and deleting then reinstalling your bundle if you use bundle --path) will improve the startup performance of Spring.
Could not find gem 'pg' in any of the gem sources listed in your Gemfile or available on this machine.
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
```

So I did bundle install then I got this:

```
An error occurred while installing pg (0.18.4), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install pg -v '0.18.4'` succeeds before bundling.
```

I did brew install postgres to solve this but it still didn't work. Also I  put 'gem pg '0.18.4' on Gemfile then did bundle install but still didn't work.

I need your help!
below is my Gemfile

```
# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.2.5.1'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
gem 'sqlite3', group: [:development, :test]

gem 'pg', group: :production
#gem 'pg', '0.18.4'

gem 'rails_12factor', group: :production
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug'
end

group :development do
  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> in views
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'

  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
end
```

Comment: What happens when you run `gem install pg -v '0.18.4'`

Comment: From what I can see the pg gem is setup to be installed for production only, so you would have to run bundle --without production for that to work correctly but secondly why would you run SQLite in development and pg in production? I think some queries could differ and why would you have a different database structure in development and production

Comment: Sorry I forgot to put that. I got "Done installing documentation for  after 0 seconds" when I run gem install pg -v '0.18.4'.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to clean and rebuild you gem bundle? You can do it with command `bundle clean --force` and then `bundle install` again.

**Please be advised**: the clean command will remove all your gems.

Post back the result of such commands if you decide to run them.